# Conditional Time-differences

Tags: r, data.table

I have group-year observations (`g`, `t`) of a variable `x`. I'd like to compute the first-difference of `x` `t-(t-1)` group-wise, under the condition that we have an observation at `t+1`.

That is, if my data was

```
  t  x  g
  1  1  1 
  2  2  1 
  3  2  1 
  1  1  2 
  2  10 2
```

The simple first difference `dt[by=list(t, g), order(t), list(t=t[-1], diff=(x))]`  would give me something along the lines of

```
 t  x  g
 2  1  1
 3  0  1 
 2  9  2
```

However, as we do not have observations for `g=1` at `t=4` and no observation for `g=2` at `t=3`, my conditional difference (and hence the **desired output**) is

```
 t  x  g
 2  1  1
```

How would I achieve this efficiently using `r` and `data.table`?

Comment: Please add the desired result data.table.

Comment: The last output is the desired result, Ill emphasize that.

Comment: What's `year[-1]`? You don't have such variable in the provided data set

Comment: Whoups, fixed that. This comes from trying to write pseudo-general code that's not specifically my dataset with all its weird names... :o

Comment: Your code still doesn't give me the described result